# Готовая реализация сервера для аккаунтов и авторизации

Tags: github, веб-сервер, bitbucket

Есть определенный набор задач, которые кочуют из проекта в проект, а именно регистрация, авторизация, подтверждение имейла, сброс пароля, вход через социальные сети. Причем это нужно почти любому веб приложению. Еще например часто встречается пополнение баланса пользователя.

Есть какой-нибудь готовый, поддерживаемый, проект, что-то типо микросервиса, который бы предоставлял апи, по которому я мог бы зарегистрировать пользователя, авторизовать, сбросить ему пароль, без нужды написания крудов, сервисов, контроллеров?